# Copy-PnPFile PowerShell online but with different site collection

Tags: powershell, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I am writing a powershell script to copy files (documents) from a OneDrive site to a SharePoint site. They are in different site collections.

I am using this command:

```
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $file.fieldvalues.FileRef -TargetUrl $destpath -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists -Force -ErrorVariable errors -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

But it is giving me 404 error. I think the error is coming from the -sourceurl parameter since they are from different site collection. I tried adding the whole url of the source file but it gave me this error:

```
Copy-PnPFile : Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

I can just load the files using `$docLibrary = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents")`, but I'm not sure how to copy its contents to the SharePoint site. Is there any possible approach?

P.S: I am getting the files form the onedrive using  `$items = Get-PnPListItem -List Documents -PageSize 1000.`